# transaction "unconfirmed," no idea what the problem is, running updated bitcoin core

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

The transaction 0ee906dd3a240d3776d609853a7e855ed813b8a1e51328405145a8cffecbb804 has been unconfirmed for six hours. I have no idea what the problem, it just says "unconfirmed transaction!". Is there anything I can do? My bitcoin core was recently updated so i don't think it's a transaction fee problem.

Answer (score 0):

[There is currently a backlog of about 52,000 unconfirmed Bitcoin transactions.](https://blockchain.info/unconfirmed-transactions)

The transaction [0ee906dd3a240d3776d609853a7e855ed813b8a1e51328405145a8cffecbb804](https://blockchain.info/tx/0ee906dd3a240d3776d609853a7e855ed813b8a1e51328405145a8cffecbb804) will be confirmed eventually.

At the very worst, the transaction will get dropped and the coins will still be in the sending address.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent this from happening, increase your transaction fee to raise your transaction priority.  This will prioritize the transaction and miners will confirm it faster.